# How to pass and get value with external js file

Tags: javascript

Can I pass a value to a js file like this, if not, how ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="create.js/280"></script>
```

Yes, you notice that I have a parameter 280 which I want to use in my create.js

how could I pass a slash parameter to the js file itself ?

Comment: Why would you want to? If you want to parameterize something it's a function *(/etc)*, not a file. Yes, you **could**, if the server returning the JS file grabs the parameter and does something with it. I would recommend against doing that.

Comment: and if you need it in your code (contained in a static file) then you _could_ set a global variable (!!!) before including that file or - much better - have it as a parameter in a function (defined in `create.js` you call when appropriate.

Comment: It is possible in one or more roundabout ways. What are you trying to accomplish with the variable?

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional when the value is `text/javascript`; omitting it will save you twenty or so bytes and remove the opportunity to break your script with a typo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) will give you access to the currently running `<script>` element.

You can then use [the `getAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to read the `src` and parse it however you like (e.g. a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)) to split the `280` from the rest of the URL.

I'd recommend moving the `280` to a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and then reading it with [`document.currentScript.dataset.yourDataName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). Aside from being simply easier, it will allow the script to be cached even if the number changes.

```html
<script data-your-data-name="280">
  console.log(document.currentScript.dataset.yourDataName);
</script>
```

Comment: Have any example please?

Comment: @MdAlamgirHossain — There's already a live example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it retains data from all other external scripts.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "it retains data from all other external scripts".